# xmlns attribute not getting set in xslt transformation

Tags: java, xslt

I am passing a stylesheet and an input stream to `Transformer` class to get output XML.

The relative variable passed to xmlns is not getting replaced in the result.

Input Stream:

```
"http://www.abc.com/foo/bar"
+"EventCommon"
+"application,xsd:string"
+"companyId,xsd:string"
+"operator,xsd:string"
+"today,xsd:date"
+"transactionStage,xsd:string"
```

Stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
  version="2.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
>
  <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="var_main_namespace" select="array/data[@attribute=1][@value=1][@subvalue=1]" />
    <xsd:schema xmlns="($var_main_namespace)" targetNamespace="{$var_main_namespace}" elementFormDefault="qualified" />
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output XML:

```
<xsd:schema 
  xmlns="($var_main_namespace)" 
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
  targetNamespace="http://www.abc.com/foo/bar" 
  elementFormDefault="qualified"
/>
```

The code snippet:

```
 TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
 StreamSource sc = new StreamSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(new String(c).getBytes()));
 Transformer transformer = tFactory.newTransformer(sc);
 ByteArrayOutputStream outputxml = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
 transformer.transform(
     new StreamSource(
        new ByteArrayInputStream(new String(c2).getBytes())
     ), 
     new StreamResult(outputxml)
 );
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Compare `xmlns="($...)"` and `targetNamespace="{$...}"`. What do you notice?

Answer (score 0):

Leaving aside the `($...)` vs. `{$...}` typo, this won't work because `xmlns` is not an attribute, it's a namespace declaration.

Not being attributes, namespace declarations in literal result elements are *not* treated as attribute value templates and you can't create them using `<xsl:attribute>`.  But as you're apparently using XSLT 2.0 you *can* create them using [`<xsl:namespace>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#creating-namespace-nodes)

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:variable name="var_main_namespace" select="array/data[@attribute=1][@value=1][@subvalue=1]" />
  <xsd:schema targetNamespace="{$var_main_namespace}" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xsl:namespace name="" select="$var_main_namespace" />
  </xsd:schema>
</xsl:template>
```

For this to work with the Java code you've given your default `TransformerFactory` needs to be one that supports XSLT 2.0, such as Saxon 9.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Ian. But when i give the <xsl:namespace> tag, it throws the following error:ERROR:  'Unsupported XSL element 'http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform:namespace''
javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unsupported XSL element 'http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform:namespace'
 at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:736)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:340)

Comment: Thanks Ian, the solution works fine after changing the stylesheet to 2.0 version and also using SAXON 9 processor.